# I am having trouble saving an array in a Rails 2.2.2 app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

in the controller:

```
@reminders = Reminder.find(:all, :conditions => ["group_id = ? and remind_at < ?", g.id, @three_days_ago])
@reminders.each do |r|
  r.remind_at = DateTime.now
end

@reminders.each(&:save!)
p "*** test ***"
```

This approach is working in another part of my code, but for some reason there is no error message but the data is not saving. It is not an attributes accessible problem. The test message is printing in the console so the process is not skipping over that part of the code. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Does it work if you add `r.save!` after setting #remind_at?

Comment: looks ok - but why not try @reminders.each do |r|
  r.update_attribute(:remind_at, DateTime.now)
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but it's not a very efficient way of doing things. You could potentially have a very large number of reminders which could potentially require multiple GBs of memory to load. Fetching `all` of anything is inherently risky.

A better solution is to just get the database to do it:

```
Reminder.update_all(:remind_at => Time.now)
```

Even on a large table, this operation should complete fairly quickly and doesn't require loading, adjusting, validating and saving each model.

Comment: sorry. i was trying to keep things simple but should have put the condition into the statement. Not every record should receive the update. my mistake.

Comment: The good news is that `update_all` has a second argument that's the conditions to be applied. You can also scope it in advance with `where` in newer versions of Rails.